# How do I show distinct week?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the SQL code based on "**Running total**" concept.My code is calculating accurate running total but i need to show the running total only after completion of every week not by dates.?

```
Select DISTINCT SD1.[Week], 
    SD1.[Allocation], 
    SD1.[Subsidiaries],
    SD1.[Month],
    SD1.[Date],
    (SD1.[Daily Sale]+IsNull(SUM(SD2.[Daily Sale]),0)) as 'Running Total'
from [dbo].[Solar data] SD1 
    left join [dbo].[Solar data] SD2 on SD1.[Subsidiaries]=SD2.[Subsidiaries]
        and SD2.[Date]&lt;SD1.[Date] And SD1.[Month]=SD2.[Month]
where SD1.[Subsidiaries]='WCL' 
group by SD1.[Allocation],
    SD1.[Month],
    SD1.[Subsidiaries],
    SD1.[Daily Sale],
    SD1.[Week],SD1.[Date]
order by SD1.[Week]
```

```
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| Subsidiaries  | Allocation | Daily Sale |   Date    | Month  | Week  |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| WCL           |       1075 | 44.93      | 2-Jan-17  | Jan-17 | Week1 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 44.51      | 3-Jan-17  | Jan-17 | Week1 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 53.68      | 8-Jan-17  | Jan-17 | Week2 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 41.45      | 9-Jan-17  | Jan-17 | Week2 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 40.97      | 15-Jan-17 | Jan-17 | Week3 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 55.9       | 16-Jan-17 | Jan-17 | Week3 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 43.89      | 22-Jan-17 | Jan-17 | Week4 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 44.36      | 23-Jan-17 | Jan-17 | Week4 |
| WCL           |       1075 | 35.13      | 29-Jan-17 | Jan-17 | Week5 |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+--------+---------------+
| Week   | Running total |
+--------+---------------+
| Week1  | 89.44         |
| Week2  | 184.57        |
| Week3  | 281.44        |
| Week4  | 369.69        |
| Week5  | 404.82        |
+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please add your table structure, some test data and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try

```
Select DISTINCT SD1.[Week], 
    SD1.[Allocation], 
    SD1.[Subsidiaries],
    SD1.[Month],
    SD1.[Date],
    SUM(Daily Sale) as 'Running Total'
from [dbo].[Solar data] SD1 
where SD1.[Subsidiaries]='WCL' 
group by SD1.[Allocation],
    SD1.[Month],
    SD1.[Subsidiaries],
    SD1.[Daily Sale],
    SD1.[Week],SD1.[Date]
order by SD1.[Week]
```

This would sum up the sales in one row